# Alternative way to do onclick hide/show function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript that on each value on dropdown will hide/show specific fields.

On my case i have 17 values on my dropdown. then I have hide/show 100 field base on drop down values.

My script works fine but the problem is script is too long.

Please check my script below

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#inputOption_1_2').on('change',function(){
if( $(this).val()==="Apartment" ){
    //Unitinfo
$('#20').show(); //bedroom
$('#19').show(); //bathroom
$('#1176').show(); //type of floorplan
$('#1063').show(); //no. of parking
$('#1177').show(); //Indoor Area
$('#1078').show(); //Balcony Area
$('#1179').show(); //Terrace Area
$('#1191').show(); //Price
$('#1192').show(); //REF#
$('#1193').show(); //RERA #
$('#1194').hide(); //Storey
$('#1195').hide(); //Plot Area
$('#1196').hide(); //Hotel Brand
$('#1197').hide(); //Built up Area
$('#1198').hide(); //Type of use
$('#1199').hide(); //Total Capacity
$('#1200').hide(); //No of kitchen
$('#1201').hide(); //No of dining
$('#1172').hide(); //Total Area
$('#1202').hide(); //Total Built up area
$('#1203').hide(); //Total Plot Area
$('#1071').hide(); //License Authority
$('#1211').hide(); //Nature of Business
$('#1212').hide(); //Total Price
$('#1204').hide(); //Area
//Decor
$('#1000').hide(); //Furnish
$('#1084').hide(); //Decoration
$('#1085').hide(); //Kitchen Type
$('#1087').hide(); //Floor Materials
$('#1086').hide(); //Window type
$('#1088').hide(); //Window Type
$('#1091').show(); //Smart System
$('#1089').hide(); //Private Garage
$('#1013').hide(); //Private Swimming Pool
$('#1006').show(); //Built in Wardrobe
$('#1138').hide(); //BBQ Area
$('#1205').hide(); //Bathroom Type
$('#1061').hide(); //Fitted
$('#1092').hide(); //Pantry
$('#1206').hide(); //Shared Meeting Room
$('#1207').hide(); //Shared Reception
//View
$('#1080').show(); //Main Direction
$('#1136').show(); //Master Bed
$('#1137').show(); //Other Bed
$('#1167').show(); //Kitchen Direction
$('#1166').show(); //Entrance
$('#1181').show(); //Primary view
$('#1182').show(); //View from Master bed
$('#1183').show(); //View from Other bed
$('#1168').show(); //Kitchen View
//Brand
$('#1140').show(); //Cooker   
$('#1141').show(); //Fridge
$('#1142').show(); //Washing Machine
$('#1143').show(); //Dryer
$('#1144').show(); //Dishwasher
$('#1145').show(); //Floor
$('#1146').show(); //Furniture
$('#1147').show(); //Bathroom
$('#1208').hide(); //Elevator
//Status
$('#1170').show(); //Rent Status
$('#1193').show(); //Tenancy Vacating Letter
$('#1095').show(); //Vacant on transfer
$('#1148').show(); //Rent Period
$('#1092').show(); //Expirty Date
$('#1093').show(); //Vacating Letter
$('#1094').show(); //Vacating Date
//Building Info
$('#1057').show(); //Building Name
$('#7').hide(); //Community
$('#1187').hide(); //Sub Community
$('#1186').show(); //Master Community
$('#1003').hide(); //Developer
$('#1044').hide(); //Year Completion
$('#1209').hide(); //Community Management 
$('#1169').show(); //Building Management
$('#1005').show(); //Annual Service Charge
$('#1101').hide(); //Cooling System
$('#1002').hide(); //Cooker Type
$('#1103').hide(); //Total Floors
$('#1104').hide(); //Building Heigts
$('#1105').hide(); //Building Color
$('#1106').hide(); //Ext Material
}
else if.....
</script>
```

Here's my html below

```
<div class="col-lg-3" id="<?php echo $val_option['id']; ?>">
                <label class="control-label"><?php echo $required_notice . $val_option['option'] ?><?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>

                <div class="controls" >
                    <?php echo form_input('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, set_value('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, isset($estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key]) ? $estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key] : ''), 'class="form-control ' . $val_option['type'] . '" id="inputOption_' . $key . '_' . $val_option['id'] . '" placeholder="' . $val_option['option'] . '" ' . $required_text . ' ' . $max_length_text) ?>


                </div>
                </div>
```

Note: I hide my field using div id **$val_optiond['id']**
Anyone have suggestion/alternative way to do this function?

Because this method will takes time to do it and maintain I think.

Thankyou!

Comment: Use a `class` name. Give all related elements a class of the `options` value. Hide all elements and then show `$('.'+this.value).show();`

Comment: Add your `html`

Comment: when `#inputOption_1_2` is something other than Apartment, then the fileds like $('#20') are some other fields or the same list of fields?

Comment: @S.Serp they are same all list of fields then hide based on #inputOption_1_ ...

Comment: @Mr.x Html added

Comment: @CarlvicLim Here is a simple example [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21h0j4gc/) Also please display the rendered `HTML`

Comment: @NewToJS I added my to my question. This way looks fine but first I will analyze first if its fit on my structure. Thanks

Comment: @NewToJS good method! but if the fields are a long list, when you hide them all at first and then show selected fields, it will cause a blink (some items disappear and shown again) which may be annoying for user...

Comment: @S.Serp a simple edit to the selector can fix that. `$('.items:not(.'+$(this).val()+')')`  [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21h0j4gc/1/) For better visual of this working [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21h0j4gc/2/) you can see it only fades out the relevant elements.

Comment: @NewToJS yes, why you didn't post it as your answer to be able to up-vote it? ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to get a shorter js function is as following:

```
var fieldIds = [20, 19, 1176, 1063, ..., 1194, 1195, ...];

var visiblityData = {
  "Apartment": [1,0,1,...], //according to fieldIds, first item determines visibility of first fieldId (#20), ...
  "House": [0,1,1,...], //these data could also be stated as a string "011..."
  ...
};

$('#inputOption_1_2').on('change',function(){

    var vis = visiblityData[$(this).val()]; //eg: visiblityData["Apartment"]
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldIds.length; i++) //loop through the fields
    {
        var f = "#" + fieldIds[i]; //eg '#20', '#19', '#1176' ...
        $(f).toggle(vis[i]==1); //equal to: if (vis[i]) $(f).show(); else $(f).hide();
    }

});
```

---

Here is a working **demo**:

```js
var fieldIds = [20, 19, 1176, 1194];

var visiblityData_1_2 = {
  "All": [1,1,1,1], //according to fieldIds, first item determines visibility of first fieldId (#20), ...
  "Apartment": [0,0,1,1], //these data could also be stated as a string "1010..."
  "House": [1,0,1,0], 
};

var visiblityData_1_10 = { //this is for second drop down
  "All": [1,1,1,1],
  "Rent": [1,0,0,1], // only 20, 1194 will be visible
};


$('#inputOption_1_2').on('change', function(){
    var vis = visiblityData_1_2[$(this).val()]; //eg: visiblityData["Apartment"]
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldIds.length; i++) //loop through the fields
    {
        $("#" + fieldIds[i]).toggle( vis[i] == 1 ); //if (vis[i]) $(f).show(); else $(f).hide();
    }
});

$('#inputOption_1_10').on('change', function(){
    var vis = visiblityData_1_10[$(this).val()]; //eg: visiblityData["Rent"]
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldIds.length; i++) //loop through the fields
    {
        $("#" + fieldIds[i]).toggle( vis[i] == 1 ); 
    }
});

$('#inputOption_1_2').change();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<select id="inputOption_1_2">
  <option value="All">All Items</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="House">House</option>
</select>

<select id="inputOption_1_10">
  <option value="All">All Items</option>
  <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
</select>

<div id="20">20</div>
<div id="19">19</div>
<div id="1176">1176</div>
<div id="1194">1194</div>
```

Comment: I try this one but when I try to select values on my dropdown nothing happen.

1 means show right?
and 0 to hide.

Comment: there was a typo, `toggle` need a `boolean` and those 0,1 values for hide/show are not detected as boolean in this jquery function. `toggle( vis[i]==1 )` did work. test updated answer again

Comment: Ok works fine on small list and will be test on large list. And one more thing if I want to add another dependent field. Example I want to hide/show fields  on Dropdown1(inputOption_1_2) an dropdown2(inputOption_1_10) this script is applicable?

Comment: Ok, Now I hide/show my fields thru select id ="inputOption_1_2" right??

then I have another dropdown which is select id ="inputOption_1_10" 
also on this dropdown i want to hide/show fields like "inputOption_1_2"

so the scenario will be like this

Example
I have 4 fields 20,19,1176,1194

on "inputOption_1_2" I select Apartment I will hide #20,#19,
then on inputOption_1_10 I select for Rent I will hide #1176 and show #20 then the result will be #20 and #1194.

This is possible on this function?

Comment: yes, if you know visibility of all items when second drop down is selected. (i mean if these 2 drop downs set visibility of fields independent of each other)

Comment: Ok, I just want to make sure because I will apply this instead of a long method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163131/discussion-between-carlvic-lim-and-s-serp).